# Websphere error while trying to call EJB methods on another server

Tags: java, websphere, ejb-2.x

I'm using **EJB 2.x**. I have 2 machines, both of them on **WebSphere 7.0**. 
On each of them deployed different application. When I try from one application (on machine1) to call the EJB of the other application (on machine2), I am getting the following error:

> java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 0x4942f999 No; nested
>   exception is:     org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: Profile data of length
>   0x3f400000  while reading IOR Profile  vmcid: IBM  minor code: 999 
>   completed: No

Does anyone have idea how to solve this problem, cause I'm pretty much stuck on this issue.
Thanx!

**Edit**:

For EJB call I used common approach:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://remote.host.com:2809");
props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "remote_user");
props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "remote_pwd");
Context ctx = new InitialContext(props);
Object objRef = ctx.lookup("servicemanagerJndiName");
ServiceManagerHome home = (ServiceManagerHome) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(
        objRef, ServiceManagerHome.class);
manager = home.create();
manager.getMethod();...
```

The thing is that this service call correctly inoked on remote server, and the response is sent, just on the client side, I am receiving following error:

> And this is the error I receive[SoapConnectorThreadPool : 5] [] ERROR
>   java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 0x4942f999 No; nested
>   exception is:     org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: Profile data of length
>   0x3f400000  while reading IOR Profile  vmcid: IBM  minor code: 999 
>   completed: No     at
>   com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.UtilDelegateImpl.mapSystemException(UtilDelegateImpl.java:277)
>     at javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.mapSystemException(Util.java:84)    at
>   com.host.local.manager._ServiceManager_Stub.getMethod(_ServiceManager_Stub.java):

Comment: How are you invoking the EJB on the other server? Are you using the foreign cell bindings etc?

Elaborate on the set up and provide the detailed logs so that we can try and help you out.


Manglu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully solved the problem. 
The external jar where **ServiceManager** (remote interface) & **ServiceManagerHome** (home interface) were held, has been substituted with the jar file also containing Stubs inside. The stubs were created using the *com.ibm.websphere.ant.tasks.WsEjbDeploy* **ant** task. Your ant should look somehting like this:

```
    <taskdef name="wsejbdeploy" classname="com.ibm.websphere.ant.tasks.WsEjbDeploy>
        <classpath refid="your.websphere.classpath"/>
    </taskdef>
    <target name="packEjbJar">
        <jar destfile="pre-deploy-ejb.jar">
            <metainf dir="src" includes="ejb-jar.xml" />
            <metainf dir="src" includes="ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xmi" />

            <fileset dir="your.build.classes.location">
                <include name="com/yourapp/ejb/**/*.*" />
            </fileset>
        </jar>
        <wsejbdeploy inputJar="pre-deploy-ejb.jar"
                            wasHome="your.websphere.home"
                            workingDirectory="dist"
                            outputJar="ejb.jar"
                            codegen="false"
                            keepGenerated="false"
                            quiet="false"
                            noValidate="true"
                            noWarnings="false"
                            noInform="false"
                            failonerror="true"
                            trace="true"
                            classpathref="your.classpath" />
    </target>
```

After this, stubs will be packaged in **ejb.jar**. After redeploying with this new jar my application works just fine. **Note** You will need to populate *ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xmi* in order for stubs to be created. Here is the example content of this file:

```
<ejbbnd:EJBJarBinding xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:ejbbnd="ejbbnd.xmi" xmlns:ejb="ejb.xmi" xmi:id="ejb-jar_ID_Bnd">
  <ejbJar href="META-INF/ejb-jar.xml#ejb-jar_ID"/>
  <ejbBindings xmi:id="Session_ServiceManager_Bnd" jndiName="com.host.local.manager.ServiceManager">
    <enterpriseBean xmi:type="ejb:Session" href="META-INF/ejb-jar.xml#Session_ServiceManager"/>
  </ejbBindings>
</ejbbnd:EJBJarBinding>
```

P.S. Also, to access remote beans (on **machine2**) from **machine1** I needed to set
*C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts* file, and add in the list IP and the name of remote 
machine2

Hope this info is going to be useful for somebody.